# ListSliceContourPlot3D with non-opaque stacked planes

Tags: plotting

I'd like to make a `ListSliceContourPlot3D` in *Mathematica* with using the stacked planes (x, y, or z) for the contours, but I'd like the planes to have an opacity < 1, so one can partially see through the plane to the next one down. I've tried setting the opacity and it doesn't look like an option for that plot type. Still, I'm hoping there is a way.

Answer (score 12):

I took this code out of the examples given in [`ListSliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceContourPlot3D.html)
. I only added the option `BaseStyle -> Opacity[.6]`.

```
data = Table[x + y + z, {z, -1, 1, 0.2}, {y, -1, 1, 0.2}, {x, -1, 1, 0.2}];

Table[
  ListSliceContourPlot3D[data, sl,
    BaseStyle -> Opacity[.6],
    PlotLabel -> sl], 
  {sl, {"XStackedPlanes", "YStackedPlanes", "ZStackedPlanes"}}]
```

[image: plots]

Answer (score 5):

Here are *two* additional ways to do this.

### 1. `ContourShading`

[`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html) is an option for `ListContourPlot3D` that allows one to specify graphics directives for each contour surface. However, such directives have to be specified explicitly, so I found it rather awkward to use:

```
Table[
 ListSliceContourPlot3D[
  data,
  sl,
  ContourShading -> (Directive[#, Opacity@0.6] & /@ ColorData[35, "ColorList"]),
  PlotLabel -> sl],
 {sl, {"XStackedPlanes", "YStackedPlanes", "ZStackedPlanes"}}]
```

> [image: plot1]

The advantage here is that one can use a well-documented *Mathematica* plot option. The disadvantage is that it is (in my opinion) clunky. (Since only the option value `Automatic` defaults to the `ColorFunction`, in other cases the color has to be specifically provided for each directive, which makes using a color function messy, as it has to be appropriately scaled and sampled. Here, I just used a discrete list.)

#### 2. Postprocessing

One can also change the properties of the `Polygons` making up the contour filling after the plot has been made. It is matter of finding the relevant parts of the produced plot and changing them. In this case, we want to make all the polygons opaque, so after some digging around, we find that they are all in `GraphicsGroup` constructions, so we try the following:

```
Table[
 ListSliceContourPlot3D[
  data,
  sl,
  PlotLabel -> sl] /. g_GraphicsGroup :> Sequence[Opacity@0.6, g],
 {sl, {"XStackedPlanes", "YStackedPlanes", "ZStackedPlanes"}}]
```

> [image: plot2]

This method has the advantage that all of the properties of the original plot are preserved. The disadvantage is that one has to do a little spelunking into the innards of the plot, but after some practice, it is not so bad.

Comment: For `ListSliceContourPlot3D` (and all `List*` plots), you don't need `Evaluate`, you just need to wrap it parentheses to get the correct precedence.

Comment: @rcollyer Good to know!